# how to place bg image with css

Tags: html, css, background

Hi is it possible to place bg image to fixed position from the center of a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/MNwZb/1/)

```
div
{
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/50x50) no-repeat;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
   /*margin: offset here*/ 
}
```

Here, the top left point of the image is at the center of the page. You can offset this by adding a margin.

So in your case you need to offset it 100px right from center - so add `margin-left:100px`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Use the Following code.

```
body {
  background: url("yourimage.gif") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: background: 50% 50% covers the background-position: center.  no need for both

Answer (score 0):

yes,

```
{
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: but I want to place the bg image to 100px right from page center

Comment: @user1081978  Put your image inside the div and assign the css to it.